# How to use a set of values returned from a function to plot points on a graph using python graphics

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

```
seed(20190101)
def random_walk(n):
    x = 0
    y = 0
    for i in range(n):
        step = random.choice(["N","S","E","W"])
        if step == 'N':
            y = y + 1
        elif step == "S":
            y = y - 1
        elif step == "E":
            x = x + 1
        else:
            x = x - 1
    return (x,y)

for i in range(50):
    walk = random_walk(100)
    all_steps.append(abs(walk[0]) + abs(walk[1]))
steps_mean = statistics.mean(all_steps) #Only after the loop
steps_max = max(all_steps)
steps_min = min(all_steps)
steps_variance = statistics.stdev(all_steps)
print("Max is",steps_max)
print("Mean is",steps_mean)
print("Min is",steps_min)
print("variance is",steps_variance)
print("Pa random walk of 100 steps")

for x,y in random_walk
   (turtle?)
```

Okay, so I have this program that is essentially a random walk, and the first function returns x and y coordinates, and the for loop does a 100 trials.

I'm trying to get the x and y coordinates from every trial and print them out in a screen using python turtle graphics, and i am a bit puzzled on how I would return all of the x and y values, and put them inside a graph. Would I use a for loop like I did before? Do i just need to call the function and use it?

I'm confused.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  You're asking for tutorial help that is available on line in many other places and formats; we expect you to use those resources before posting here.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to plot the ending locations as x-y coordinates, the something like this may work for Turtle (make sure to add `import turtle` at the beginning of your script):

```
turtle_plot = turtle.Turtle()

for i in range(50):
    walk = random_walk(100)
    all_steps.append(abs(walk[0]) + abs(walk[1]))

    turtle_plot.goto(walk[0], walk[1])
```

This will not work in Jupyter without the ipyturtle extension. **However**, I highly suggest you just use matplotlib, the primary plotting library in Python. You can change your loop to this:

```
x_loc = []
y_loc = []

for i in range(50):
    walk = random_walk(100)
    all_steps.append(abs(walk[0]) + abs(walk[1]))

    x_loc.append(walk[0])
    y_loc.append(walk[1])
```

Then you can plot the coordinates using matplotlib:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(x_loc, y_loc)
```

---

#### Edit

Per the comment about recreating this for different random walk functions:

```
def plot_random_walk(func_name, n, npoints):

    x_loc = []
    y_loc = []

    for i in range(npoints):

        walk = func_name(n)

        x_loc.append(walk[0])
        y_loc.append(walk[1])

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    ax.plot(x_loc, y_loc)

    return(ax)
```

For example, you would call the function above using the same parameters from the original answer:

```
a = plot_random_walk(func_name = random_walk, n = 100, npoints = 50)
```

Comment: So i have multiple functions for the random walk, so would i just write 3 for loops with the variable for the walk = random_walk to be different? Like for instance I have a function called "father walk". Would I modify it to be walk = father_walk(100) and keep the for loop to be the same?

Comment: @Oklol2958 if you find yourself reusing the same piece of code often, it is best to turn it into a function. You could write a function that takes in the random walk function name and creates the plot

Comment: @Oklol2958 I've edited the original answer to help you out with this